# Error with typo3_console: Could not scan for classes inside "/typo3conf/ext/typo3_console/Array"

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-console

The TYPO3 extension `typo3_console` throws the error:

> Could not scan for classes inside "/typo3conf/ext/typo3_console/Array"
>   which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a bug in TYPO3 core itself and has been solved with the version `7.6.11` and above. The solution is to update to latest 7.6 version.